# Complex logarithms issue

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

So, we know $\log(x)$ is real when $x>0$ and it has an imaginary component when $x<0$:
\begin{equation}\log(x) =\log(e^{i\theta}|x|) = i\theta + \log(|x|)
\end{equation}

However
\begin{equation} 
\log(x) = \frac{1}{2} \log(x^{2})
\end{equation}
Maybe there is an issue here (or else I don't know where it is), so point it out please.

In particular when $x$ is real:
\begin{equation} 
\log(x) = \frac{1}{2} \log(x^{2}) = \frac{1}{2} \log(|x|^{2}) = \log(|x|)
\end{equation}
And that's quite weird.

In general:
\begin{equation} 
\log(e^{i\theta}|x|) = \frac{1}{2} \log(e^{2i\theta}|x|^{2}) = i\theta + \frac{1}{2}\log(|x|^{2})
\end{equation}

However if $\theta=\{0,\pi\}$, then $e^{2i\theta}=1$, in the common case where we have a $2\pi$ redundancy, or how it's called.

So:
\begin{equation} 
\log(-x) = i\pi + \log(|x|) = \log(|x|) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\log(x) = \log(|x|)
\end{equation}

Where is the issue in these statements?
I know there should be at least a big one, don't know where

Comment: The equality $\log\left(e^{i\theta}|x|\right)=i\theta+\log(|x|)$ makes no sense. Note that $e^{i\theta}=e^{i(\theta+2\pi)}$. Are you claiming that $i\theta+\log(|x|)=i(\theta+2\pi)+\log(|x|)$?

Comment: Indeed, generalising logarithm to a function on the complex plane is not straightforward. It can be done, but some arbitrary choices have to be made, and some properties will be lost.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $log(e^{i(\theta+2k\pi) }|x|)$ $= log(e^{i(\theta+2k\pi)}) + log(|x|)$ $= i(\theta+2k\pi) + log(|x|)$ If I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Matteo The big issue is: $\exp(i(\theta + 2k\pi)) = \exp(i\theta)$ for all $k$, yet obviously $i(\theta + 2k\pi) \neq i\theta$ when $k\neq0$. In other words, function $\exp$ is not injective on the complex plane, so you cannot hope for a proper inverse function. You can still define a logarithm function as a partial inverse, but it will only be a partial inverse. Just like taking the square root is not a perfect inverse of squaring: $\sqrt{x^2}$ does not always equal $x$; likewise, no matter your definition of $\log$, you can't hope to have $\log(\exp(x)) = x$ for all complex numbers.

Comment: Are you *really* claiming that $i\theta+\log(|x|)=i(\theta+2\pi)+\log(|x|)$? In other words, are you really claiming that $\pi=0$?

Answer (score 1):

> \begin{equation}\log(x) =\log(e^{i\theta}|x|) = i\theta + \log(|x|)
> \end{equation}

The first mistake is here, since $e^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta+i2k\pi}$, then you get

\begin{equation}i\theta + \log(|x|)=i\theta+i2k\pi+\log(|x|)
\end{equation}

which doesn't hold for $k\neq 0$

> However
> \begin{equation} 
> \log(x) = \frac{1}{2} \log(x^{2})
> \end{equation}

The second mistake is here. Let $x=-1$

\begin{equation} 
\log(-1) = \frac{1}{2} \log((-1)^{2})=0
\end{equation}

which doesn't hold.

Comment: Ah, ok. For the first issue there is no problem as I can choose what riemann surface I'm on. On the second mistake I simply forgot that the square root should be applied to the angle on the complex plane of |x| too. |x| is surely positive, but we should have an $e^{2ik\pi}|x|$ to take the square root of. The real deal is that we don't want that $2ik\pi$ to show, as you've wrote in the first mistake, as it's not that simple. If we leave it in the log, then it all works out without ugly terms out of it.

Comment: Before you compute it, you have to specify the branch for the argument angle, otherwise, it will give wrong result.